# Include 3rd party library in VS code in C++ project

Tags: c++, g++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to include a 3rd party library in my first C++ project.

Here is the file structure:

[image]

Here is the code:

[image]

If I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
Starting build... /usr/bin/g++ -g /home/?/projects/c++/test.cpp -o /home/?/projects/c++/test
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cci5qRjP.o: in function `main': /home/?/projects/c++/test.cpp:7: undefined reference to `omp::HandEvaluator::HandEvaluator()'
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cci5qRjP.o: in function `omp::Hand::Hand(unsigned int)': /home/?/projects/c++/include/OMPEval/omp/Hand.h:49: undefined reference to `omp::Hand::CARDS'
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cci5qRjP.o: in function `omp::Hand::empty()': /home/?/projects/c++/include/OMPEval/omp/Hand.h:114: undefined reference to `omp::Hand::EMPTY'
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cci5qRjP.o: in function `omp::HandEvaluator::perfHash(unsigned int)': /home/?/projects/c++/include/OMPEval/omp/HandEvaluator.h:39: undefined reference to `omp::HandEvaluator::PERF_HASH_ROW_OFFSETS'
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cci5qRjP.o: in function `unsigned short omp::HandEvaluator::evaluate<true>(omp::Hand const&) const': /home/?/projects/c++/include/OMPEval/omp/HandEvaluator.h:27: undefined reference to `omp::HandEvaluator::LOOKUP'
 /usr/bin/ld: /home/?/projects/c++/include/OMPEval/omp/HandEvaluator.h:31: undefined reference to `omp::HandEvaluator::FLUSH_LOOKUP'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s). The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

The code is taken for the documentation of the [library](https://github.com/zekyll/OMPEval).

c_cpp_properties.json

[image]

launch.json

[image]

tasks.json

[image]

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Do not post images of source code, post the properly formatted code.

Comment: Does this `omp` library provide any instructions for how to install and use it in VSCode? The errors look like you are not linking to any pre-compiled binaries for the library, or including the library's source files directly into your project.  Hard to answer your question without knowing how you setup your project.

Comment: There are no VS Code specific instruction just code examples.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The library source files are in the "project" (actually VSCode has no project just directory tree), but may or may not be in the makefile, and VS Code isn't configured to use the makefile, he's running a build that compiles just one file, always.

Comment: @Paolo You have a problem of figuring out how to link with the OMP library(ies). Try compiling this from the command line until you get it right, then perhaps, you'll figure out how your VS Code configuration is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever that tasks.json came from, it is not adequate for a complex project containing multiple source files.  It compiles and tries to link only a single .cpp file; this is doomed to failure when there are multiple .cpp files that are supposed to work together.

You have a file named `Makefile` in your project directory... updating tasks.json to run `make` and let make run the compiler and linker would be a good start... but you should also expect to modify the Makefile each time you add new files to your project.

Comment: that Make file came with the OMPEval (the 3rd party library I downloaded from githhub). Should I build it with make and include / link ?? the result (ompeval.a) when I build the project with g++?

Comment: You can build a static lib and link it with your application.  Or you can link all the OMPEval files individually into your application.  What doesn't work is "Build Active File" when the active file is not a complete program by itself.

Comment: how should my g++ command look like? I successfully build the OMPEval with make. Now I have in the folder (c++/include/OPMEval/opm) the new object files : CardRange.o, EquityCalcuator.o, HandEvaluator.o etc.

Comment: now it looks like this: `/usr/bin/g++ -g /home/?/projects/c++/test.cpp -I/home/?/projects/c++/include -L/home/?/projects/c++/include -o /home/?/projects/c++/test` but I am getting:
/home/?/projects/c++/test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: omp/HandEvaluator.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @Paolo `/home/?/projects/c++/test.cpp` - surely, you see something wrong there?

Comment: ou mean the question mark? I just replaced my name.